# object moves on axis that's not locked

Tags: objects, transforms

I'm trying to move an object on one axis - which I thought was one of the simplest things - but when I hit g, and then x/y/z, it locks, but then for some reason it will jump in space as I'm moving it on that one axis. This only happens when it's overlapping with other objects in space, and if I've hidden the other objects from view it doesn't happen. I've tried moving the 3D cursor everywhere I can think of, changing from global to local to all the other options - nothing has worked.

Comment: It sounds like you have some form the the Snapping tool turned on. See if the icon which looks like a classic horseshoe magnet is turned on. It will either be center top or center bot depending on your set up. You can also try toggling it with Shift + Tab.